# saving in programmer-defined folder in C#

Tags: c#, image, save, relative-path

I'm trying to save a picture in a relative path of my project. I want it to be in a folder called "images". By using this code

```
theImage.Save("\\images\\image.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

I realized by testing with an absolute path, that the folder "images" must exist for it to work. problem is, I don't know what the root folder for the project is, so I can manually create the folder in windows explorer. how can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
Directory.Create("images");
theImage.Save(@"images\image.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

`Directory.Create` will only make a folder if one does not yet exist, so no need to worry about that.  The `@` before a string literal makes it so that the only character that needs to be escaped is the `"` which is done like `""`.  Anyways, I don't think you should have to make your own folder manually now.  Also, for future reference, you can get the current working directory programmatically by using `Environment.CurrentDirectory`.

EDIT:  In that case, try:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("images");  
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"images\image.jpg";
theImage.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);`
```

Comment: hmmmm weird, the directory gets created, but the file doesn't save. i mean, the directory stays empty...

note: it's Directory.CreateDirectory. and you need the system.io

Comment: somehow, when I specify an absolute path, everything's fine. but as soon as it's relative, it doesn't save...

Comment: @Nick - That should also work.  I prefer Environment.CurrentDirectory, but I guess that is just personal preference.

Comment: This is minor, but I think Environment.CurrentDirectory can misbehave if you are running as a service. Not 100% sure on that, but I think it returns the dir of the SCM, and not the service exe itself. Not sure if .\ would behave better though. Sometimes GetType().GetExecutingAssembly() is your best option.

Comment: nick, what is GetType().GetExecutingAssembly()?  cause VS tells me that GetExecutingAssembly() doesn't exist